# What are the physical implications of a negative drag coefficient?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my differential equations textbook book I'm given this graph [image]

My friend and I were talking and he said that the "physical implication is that the faster you travel, the more the medium through which you travel pulls you." If that's correct then what thing in nature does that?

One way I was picturing this was if I were to be pushing someone on a swing and each time they came back I pushed harder. I'm not sure if that fits in with what my friend is saying, though.

Comment: ever heard about damped oscillations?

Comment: @TheDeadLegend Yes I have, and the only graphs I've ever seen for damped oscillations are ones that look like flipped versions of the one above.

Comment: It is more like a parametric resonance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_oscillator) , quite a beautiful phenomenon.